# how to parcel hashset with custom objects

Tags: android, hashmap, hashset, parcelable

i'm implementing an application in android and i need to make my objets parcelables to move between activities. I use hibernate in the server so my classes have hashsets as atribute and i don't know how to parcel.

Here is my code and my trying... but i don't know if its ok and i don't know to do el write to parcel.
Also i want to know if i did well the parcel for DATE and my other objets as atributes

```
public class Incidencia implements Parcelable {

// Atributos
private String id_incidencia;
private String estado;
private double latitud;
private double longitud;
private Date fecha_creacion;
private Date fecha_cierre;

private Puesto puesto;
private SubTipo subtipo;

private Set<iTarea> iTareas = new HashSet<iTarea>();

// Constructores
public Incidencia() {}

public Incidencia(String id, String est, double lat, double lon, Date f_cre, Date f_cie, Puesto pue, SubTipo sub, Set<iTarea> iTa) {
    this.id_incidencia = id;
    this.estado = est;
    this.latitud = lat;
    this.longitud = lon;
    this.fecha_creacion = f_cre;
    this.fecha_cierre = f_cie;
    this.puesto = pue;
    this.subtipo = sub;
    this.iTareas = iTa;
}

// Necesarios para que sea Parcelable
public Incidencia(Parcel in) {
    this.id_incidencia = in.readString();
    this.estado = in.readString();
    this.latitud = in.readDouble();
    this.longitud = in.readDouble();
    this.fecha_creacion = new Date(in.readLong());
    this.fecha_cierre = new Date(in.readLong());
    this.puesto = (Puesto)in.readParcelable(Puesto.class.getClassLoader());
    this.subtipo = (SubTipo)in.readParcelable(SubTipo.class.getClassLoader());
    this.iTareas = (Set<iTarea>) in.readHashMap(iTarea.class.getClassLoader());

}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.getId_incidencia());
    dest.writeString(this.getEstado());
    dest.writeDouble(this.getLatitud());
    dest.writeDouble(this.getLongitud());
    dest.writeLong(this.getFecha_creacion().getTime());
    dest.writeLong(this.getFecha_cierre().getTime());
    dest.writeParcelable((Parcelable) this.puesto, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable((Parcelable) this.subtipo, flags);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Incidencia> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Incidencia>() {
    public Incidencia createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Incidencia(in);
    }

    public Incidencia[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Incidencia[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: "but i dont know if its ok" : Does it work? If not, what's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: i dont know hoy to put the hashset/map in the writetoparcel function. In the this.iTareas = (Set<iTarea>) in.readHashMap(iTarea.class.getClassLoader()); i get this message Type safety: Unchecked cast from HashMap to Set<iTarea>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it won't work, mainly because a `Set` is not a `Map`. A better approach would be for you to get an array of objects from your set using the `Set.toArray` method and use the [`Parcel.writeTypedArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedArray%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) to write it to the parcel. Then you can just read the array and populate the Set yourself when recreating the object. This would require that your `iTarea` class implement `Parcelable` as well, but it is a much better solution then trying to pass a `HashSet` off as a `HashMap`.

Your other objects and dates should be fine, by the way.